# Toggling Bluetooth on and off?

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, togglebutton

Is there a simple tutorial or dose anyone have code to toggle Bluetooth on and off using a Toggle-button in eclipse building for android?

If anyone can help that will be greatly appreciated.

-Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

in your manifest file, and variables like:

```
private final integer REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
```

and

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
boolean hasBluetooth = (mBluetoothAdapter == null);
```

so that in your OnCreate you can do something like:

```
final ToggleButton togglebutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
togglebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    // Perform action on clicks
    if (togglebutton.isChecked())
    {
      if (hasBluetooth && !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
      {
        // prompt the user to turn BlueTooth on
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (hasBluetooth && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
      {
        // you should really prompt the user for permission to turn
        // the BlueTooth off as well, e.g., with a Dialog
        boolean isDisabling = mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        if (!isDisabling)
        {
           // an immediate error occurred - perhaps the bluetooth is already off?
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

where the user response to the "turn bluetooth on" prompt is caught in

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  if ((requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK))
  {
    boolean isEnabling = mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
    if (!isEnabling)
    {
      // an immediate error occurred - perhaps the bluetooth is already on?
    }
    else if (mBluetoothAdapter.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON)
    {
      // the system, in the background, is trying to turn the Bluetooth on
      // while your activity carries on going without waiting for it to finish;
      // of course, you could listen for it to finish yourself - eg, using a
      // ProgressDialog that checked mBluetoothAdapter.getState() every x
      // milliseconds and reported when it became STATE_ON (or STATE_OFF, if the
      // system failed to start the Bluetooth.)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ben Williams, This works sorta, The problem is that it doesn't change the Bluetooth state. Is that the only permission that I need.  Also it only works if I take out REQUEST_ENABLE_BT and the whole protected void code otherwise I just have errors on "onActivityResult" and "REQUEST_ENABLE_BT"

Comment: It's probably complaining because I forgot to declare REQUEST_ENABLE_BT before using it -- which is just an integer label for the intent, so sticking `private final REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1` in, say, would work.

Also, you need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN. (I'll edit this in to the other one.)

Comment: @Ben Williams, I hate to be a bother but it still doesn't turn the Bluetooth on or off. I did get rid of the errors thank you for that.

Comment: If you do `boolean b = mBluetoothAdapter.enable()`, to get the return, is b true?  After doing the enable, is `mBluetoothAdapter.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON` true?  The enable call is asynchronous, so it will return immediately, while the Bluetooth itself may take a while to start up.

Comment: @Ben Williams,I am not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: When you call mBluetoothAdapter.enable() it doesn't turn the Bluetooth on itself.  What it does, is send a request to the system for the Bluetooth to be turned on, and then immediately returns either true if that request was sent (and the Adapter's state becomes "STATE_TURNING_ON"), or false if there was an immediate error (eg, the Bluetooth was already on). While your activity carries on going, over in the system thread, separately, the system tries to turn the Bluetooth on.  If it manages to, it comes back and sets the Adapter's state to STATE_ON; if it fails, it sets the state to STATE_OFF.

Comment: @Ben Williams, So your saying that I have to wait for the Bluetooth to actually turn on?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
if(adapter != null) {
    if(adapter.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
        adapter.disable();
    } else if (adapter.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF){
        adapter.enable();
    } else {
        //State.INTERMEDIATE_STATE;
    } 
}
```

Comment: is there any permissions that I should us besides <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>?

Comment: @Christian `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>` may be needed.

@Abhilash Is it ok to disable the `bluetooth` in `onDestroy()`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public void disableBluetooth(Context context, Boolean bool) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(bool)
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    else
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: BlueTooth and Wi-Fi are different things.

Answer (score 0):

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Integer bluetooth = 1; // Turn on
Object nada = (bluetooth == 1 ? mBluetooth.enable() : mBluetooth.disable());
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Answer (score 0):

download this example this will help you

https://github.com/siddhpuraamitr/Blutooth-Toggle-Widget

Answer (score 0):

IF YOU ARE HAVING TROUBLE IN ANDROID 33 READ ME

I spent way to many hours today figuring this out, since this is the top google search here is how to create a button that will ask to turn Bluetooth on/off in android 33. Answer is in Kotlin
add a button to the fragment with the name android:id="@+id/requestBlueToothButton"

AndroidManifest.xml will need the following lines

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

```
requestBlueToothButton.setOnClickListener {
                val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager? = getSystemService(requireContext(), BluetoothManager::class.java)
                val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = bluetoothManager?.getAdapter()
                if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
                }
                if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
                    val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                    startActivity(enableBtIntent)
                }
            }
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/setup#kotlin)