# Toggle bluetooth with button in widget?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onupdate

How can I be able to toggle on bluetooth with button in the widget.

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{

}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735053/toggling-bluetooth-on-and-off

Comment: Yes but button in the widget has different method. Insted of onClickListener there is onUpdate!!