# Disable Bluetooth onClick android

Tags: android, bluetooth, onclick

how                                                                                                                                                                                                           to DISABLE bluetooth on the Onclick of a button?

```
public void btd(View view) { 
    BluetoothAdapter blue = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        blue.disable();
}
```

OR

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
         if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
             // Device does not support Bluetooth

             }else{

             if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                mBluetoothAdapter.enable();

             }else{

              mBluetoothAdapter.disable();    

             }

             }


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

the code only works if i enable bluetooth vis code, but if its enable via notificationbar, then the app gets force closed!!

Here is error Log http://justpaste.it/fd7t

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735053/toggling-bluetooth-on-and-off

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android

Comment: When an app is force-closing on you you don't need to play the guessing game. Learn how to debug your program. Read the logcat, understand the stack trace.

Comment: @Nikkajihaikjawak, any error log of `Force closing`?

Comment: http://justpaste.it/fd7t

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
   mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
}
```